# Windows 8.1 photo downloading/importing Picasa has wrong dates

Tags: windows-8.1, images, photos, picasa

When downloading photos using Picasa, for some reason Picasa seems to choose random dates for the photos. We like to put photos in folders based on date, and they are just not right. There's nothing obvious, like 1 Jan 1970, just wrong day/month in mostly the right year.

When I look at the photo information (even using Picasa), it knows when the photo was really taken, so it is just the import process, and possibly the sorting.

I tried Windows Photo Gallery, but that always wants to create folders with names like "Dec 16 2014 2:07PM - Dec 16 2014 10:21PM" (exact format may be slightly wrong). Who does that, the date would be fine. It does that even when I choose "Date + Name".

I'd be happy to understand why Picasa is messed up and fix it, how to make Photo Gallery work the way it looks like it is supposed to, or use some other tool.

FWIW, the camera is a Canon S3-IS, and the S/W that came with it was fine, but no longer available from Canon. The new ZoomBrowser-EX is terrible.